# converting currency using functions and arguments not working in c programming language

Tags: c, function, arguments

i'm trying to make a program that converts euros to dollars and dollar to euros 
bur its not working right it only converts from dollars to euros 
can any one help me and tell me where is the mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void convert(float euro);
void convert2(float dollar);

int main()
{
    char what;
    printf("if u want to convert from USD to Euro type U\n");
        printf("if u want to convert from EURO to USD type E\n");
scanf("%c", &what);
if(what = 'U')
{

    float howmany5;
    printf("how many dollars\n");
    scanf(" %f", &howmany5);
    convert2(howmany5);
}
 if(what = 'E')
{

    printf(" how many euros\n");
    float howmany;
    scanf(" %f", &howmany);
     convert(howmany);
}
 return 0;
}
void convert(float euro)
{
    float dollar = euro * 1.37;
    printf("%0.2f euro - %.02f USD", euro, dollar);
    return;
}
void convert2(float dollar)
{`enter code here`
    float euro = dollar *0.8;
    printf("%0.2f dollar - %.02f euro", dollar, euro);
    return;`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: OK i fixed it i just need to add another = sign

Comment: A trick to avoid this mistake is to use `'U' == what` instead of `what == 'U'`, so if you miss a `=`, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: oh thank u, some silly mistakes lead to perfection  :)

Comment: @user4098326  [agrees Yoda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

Answer (score 0):

you are doing assignment `=` instead of comparing `==`, the statement `what = 'U'` always evaluating to true

```
if(what == 'U')
{

    float howmany5;
    printf("how many dollars\n");
    scanf(" %f", &howmany5);
    convert2(howmany5);
}
else if(what == 'E')
{

    printf(" how many euros\n");
    float howmany;
    scanf(" %f", &howmany);
     convert(howmany);
}
```